# Installing OpenCV with Homebrew

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

if I try to install OpenCV using Homebrew I get the following error:

```
==> make
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know what operating system you used here. So I answered this question using Mac OS X. In fact, it's very easy to install OpenCV library using homebrew with following steps:

Step 0: Uninstall homebrew using the following script

```
cd `brew --prefix`
git checkout master
git ls-files -z | pbcopy
rm -rf Cellar
bin/brew prune
pbpaste | xargs -0 rm
rm -r Library/Homebrew Library/Aliases Library/Formula Library/Contributions 
test -d Library/LinkedKegs && rm -r Library/LinkedKegs
rmdir -p bin Library share/man/man1 2> /dev/null
rm -rf .git
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew
rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

Step 1: Install homebrew again

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Step 2: Once you have brew installed you can go ahead and and add homebrew/science which is where OpenCV is located using:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

If you want to see other possible options such as when compiling (such as using tbb) you can use info

```
brew info opencv
```

Step 3: Go ahead and install OpenCV now

```
brew install opencv
```

After doing this, You’re done! You can find OpenCV at

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/*.*.*/
```

Comment: "brew tap homebrew/science" no longer works in your description above, but "brew install opencv" will still do the trick